# XmlDataSource in GridView

Tags: asp.net, xml, datasource

I have an xml file with the structure mentioned below:

```
<student>
  <name>Rahul</name>
  <name>Sheela</name>
</student>
```

I need to list the names of the students in a gridview.

Answer (score 1):

You can load that file in DataSet and bind that DataSet with the GridView.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("yourfile.xml")

gridview1.DataSource = ds;
gridview1.DataBind();
```

if your dataset has more then one tables and you may need to bind with table like this

```
gridview1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; // First table in the dataset.
gridview1.DataSource = ds.Tables[1]; // Second table in the dataset.
```

After change in Question

Two elements with same name under same parent, it would be Firstname, Lastname or RahulSheela

Comment: @Waqar Janjua, if we emit Tables[0] it takes table at zero index by default. Although it is useful when we need other then first table

Answer (score 0):

You can use this synthax if it's possible for you to modify the way the XML file is rendered :

#### ASP.net markup page

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="xmlDataSource" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
              <%# Eval("name") %>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="xmlDataSource" runat="server" DataFile="~/myxmlsource.xml" />
```

In this case, you have to modifiy your XML file if it's possible because I've allways work like that before, and after trying with your format, it is not working. Maybe a bit search on internet would say it is possible but haven't checked yet. Here is the format I've used  and which is perfectly working:

#### XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<students>
    <student name="Rahul" />
    <student name="Sheela" />
</students>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a XSLT transform file for your xml and add this fil to the data source (using "configre data source ")  , this is used to re-shape your xml file so that the gridview can read it probably without the need of changing your xml structure  ,  assuiming your xml structure is like this

```
  <student>
    <name>Rahul</name>
    <name>Sheela</name>
  </student>
```

your XSLT  file should look like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns: xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com: xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl: output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match ="/">
    <student>
      <xsl:apply-templates select ="//student"/>
    </student>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match ="//student">
    <student>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </student>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

tell me if it work