# how can i convert xml document to data table in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

i am getting the following response from api as xml

```
<ROOT>

<valid>1</valid>
<org_name> test org </org_name>
<count_of_vedios>3</count_of_vedios>
<total_length>351</total_length>

    <Video1>
        <Title>The Distinguished Gentleman</Title>
        <Director>Jonathan Lynn</Director>
        <Length>112 Minutes</Length>
        <Format>DVD</Format>
        <Rating>R</Rating>
    </Video1>
    <Video2>
        <Title>Her Alibi</Title>
        <Director>Bruce Beresford</Director>
        <Length>94 Mins</Length>
        <Format>DVD</Format>
        <Rating>PG-13</Rating>
    </Video2>
    <Video3>
        <Title>Chalte Chalte</Title>
        <Director>Aziz Mirza</Director>
        <Length>145 Mins</Length>
        <Format>DVD</Format>
        <Rating>N/R</Rating>
    </Video3>

</ROOT>
```

i need to fill some fields of aspx page with the information :
org_name : test org 
count_of_vedios : 3
total_length : 351

also i need to fill gridview with the vedios that is in  nodes

### Title  |  Director  |  Length  |  Format  |  Rating  |

Comment: There's a utility to create DataSets or .NET classes from XML: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XmlDataSource in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566659/xmldatasource-in-gridview)

Answer (score 0):

dataset will have 4 tables here , so what i did is replace the vedio# tage with vedio , now the dataset will have 2 tables one for the general nodes and the another for vedios

`````
DataTable general_dt = new DataTable();
DataTable vedios_dt = new DataTable();
string xml_str = document.DocumentElement.InnerXml.ToString();
                xml_str = Regex.Replace(xml_str, @"<Video[0-9]{1,3}>", "<Video>");
                xml_str = Regex.Replace(xml_str, @"<\/Video[0-9]{1,3}>", "</Video>");

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(new System.IO.StringReader(xml_str));

                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    XmlNode newnode;
                    newnode = document.ReadNode(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml_str)));
                    if (newnode["valid"].InnerText.ToString() == "1")
                    {
                        general_dt = ds.Tables[0];
                        
                        vedios_dt = ds.Tables[1];
                    }
        }````
`````

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Directory", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Length", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Format", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Rating", typeof(string));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            List<XElement> videos = doc.Root.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("Video")).ToList();

            foreach (XElement video in videos)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    (string)video.Element("Title"),
                    (string)video.Element("Director"),
                    (string)video.Element("Length"),
                    (string)video.Element("Format"),
                    (string)video.Element("Rating")
                });

            }

        }
    }
}
```